# What does ((char *)&struct) do in C?

Tags: c

I have the following function in C code.

```
    ether_block_get((block_morse) &t_rx);
    if (t_rx.desti == self){
     if (crc_is_ok((char*) &t_rx))
      callback();
```

t_rx is a struct in another module, but I don't undrestand how I'm pasing it.

Comment: `crc_is_ok()` apparently expects a `char *` argument. So it's converting a pointer to the struct to that.

Comment: It's a cast that basically tells the compiler: pretend that `&t_rx` is a pointer to `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, &t_rx is the pointer to this structure. This is equivalent to an address in memory but of type 'pointer to this structure'. The (char*) casts this pointer to a pointer to a character. This another typical way to keep an address in memory.

Both (&t_rx) and (char*)&t_rx describe the same address in memory (maybe 0x876579ff) but typed differently. The type is important to let the compiler know about your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe crc_is_ok() function does not care what 't_rx' is, but it just want every bytes of 't_rx' to calculate some values.

> but I don't undrestand how I'm pasing it.

Where do you want to pass 't_rx'?
If you want to pass it to crc_is_ok(), you may just consider size of 't_rx' and check whether the function knows the size of 't_rx' or not.
Or if you want to pass it to callback(), it seems callback() function needs to know block_morse structure and size.

Can you explain us more intentions you want?